# How do I connect to a Laravel directory using SSH?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have SSH details and need to connect to a web app that is built using Laravel and then work on the code on my local machine. I haven't used Laravel before so am a bit lost.

The code is hosted on DigitalOcean.

Running

Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu)
PHP Version 7.1.17

I can see that I need to have Composer installed, which I've done, but need to know how to open an existing project. All of the document appears to point in the creating a new project and not opening an existing project.

Any help would be very much appreciated please.

Comment: more information about how it deployed which stuck nginx, apache the server etc ...

Comment: What do you mean open an existing project?  Just download the codebase and open it.  You really should be working from a VCS repository, but if one isn't available, downloading the files from the server should work like any other project.

Comment: Thanks @Devon, so just download all files and work on them locally then deploy like any other development?

Comment: Well, deployment is much more involved but you haven't told us anything about the project so I can't comment on that.  They may have frontend assets that need to be compiled, caches that need to be cleared, etc.   Deployment isn't something that is the same for every project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect via SSH to a server you need to do the following in your terminal:

```
ssh -p 2222 username@hostname
```

And of course, have your password in hand, also you need to check the port number, it may not be `2222`.

If you have your pair of private and public keys, you can also access in the following way:

```
ssh -p 2222 username@hostname -i path/to/public_key
```